# Exchange Server 2003 question

Tags: exchange

I am having trouble with our Exchange server at the moment and cannot work out what is wrong. Basically I can receive internal mail on the domain between exchange users but nothing from an external address comes through at all.

Tried to telnet SMTP port from inside and outside networks and it responds perfectly fine with the following message:

```
2202 <companyDNS> Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready <current time>
```

Results from MS Remote Connectivity Analyzer:

Outbound SMTP E-Mail - success with 1 warning:

```
Attempting to find the SPF record using a DNS TEXT record query.
ExRCA wasn't able to find the SPF record.
```

Inbound SMTP E-Mail - failed:

```
Testing inbound SMTP mail flow for domain <email address>.
ExRCA failed to test inbound SMTP mail flow.
        Test Steps
        Attempting to retrieve DNS MX records for domain <domain>.
One or more MX records were successfully retrieved from DNS.
        Additional Details

Testing Mail Exchanger cust11454-1.in.mailcontrol.com.
One or more SMTP tests failed for this Mail Exchanger.
        Test Steps
        Attempting to resolve the host name cust11454-1.in.mailcontrol.com in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.
        Additional Details

Testing TCP port 25 on host cust11454-1.in.mailcontrol.com to ensure it's listening and open.
The port was opened successfully.
        Additional Details

Attempting to send a test e-mail message to <email address> using MX cust11454-1.in.mailcontrol.com.
Delivery of the test message failed.
        Additional Details
The server returned status code 550 - Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 <email address>... Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [65.55.150.61]
Exception details:
Message: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 <email address>... Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [65.55.150.61]
Type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException
Stack trace:
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
 at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.SmtpMessageTest.PerformTestReally()
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Recipient Policy has our domain and it is enabled.

Comment: is your recipient policy setup correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Recipient Policy isn't configured correctly. In the Recipient Policy do you have an email address configured and enabled for this domain and is the option selected for Exchange to be responsible for the domain? If not, then that's your problem.